# Hyperbolic lagrangian in a symplectic $6$-manifold

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Is there an example of a closed symplectic $6$-manifold and a closed lagrangian sub-manifold, which is diffeomorphic to a hyperbolic $3$-manifold?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "closed" ? I interpret it as "compact without boundaries" but a compact submanifold can't be hyperbolic.

Comment: Yeah, I mean compact without boundary. Please could you explain why a compact sub-manifold cannot be hyperbolic?

Comment: Sorry this is wrong, I was thinking to something else.

Comment: You might wish to add a few tags to your question. The (symplectic-geometry) tag is not the most watched, and it is rather more symplectic *geometry* oriented than symplectic *topology* oriented, your question belonging to the latter field. Moreover my (probably exaggerated) impression is that 3-manifolds are not so well-known to many symplectic topologists. People in differential geometry/topology or in complex/kaehler geometry might be more capable of producing an example or a counter-argument, so I would advice that you try to reach them.